# Javascript Image Converter (base64) with all formats

Tags: javascript, image, hex, base64

I'm trying to script a converter (image) that pickup the checksum inside a image (form my Server) and add it to the selected image file.

But there I got 2 problems:

First problem:

It just accept jpg files, I tried everythink, but it dont work (png, gif etc.)

The second problem is, that the valid image, need to be from my server (convert.jpg)

But if I do that, I get this error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL is not an
>   object.

The line:

> readerValid.readAsDataURL(valid);

What did I do wrong? (And sry for my bad english)

My Code:

```
function hexToBytes(hex) {
    for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
    bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
    return bytes;
}
function bytesToHex(bytes) {
    for (var hex = [], i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        hex.push((bytes.charCodeAt(i) >>> 4).toString(16));
        hex.push((bytes.charCodeAt(i) & 0xF).toString(16));
    }
    return hex.join("");
}
function UpdateChecksum(pic, data) {
    var string = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(data[i])
    }
    pic = atob(pic.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ""))
    for (var i = 0; i + 1 < pic.length; ++i) {
        if (pic.charCodeAt(i) == 0xFF && pic.charCodeAt(i + 1) == 0xDB) {
            pic = pic.slice(i, pic.length)
            break
        }
    }
    var regexp =  new RegExp("(<checksum2>[0-9a-f]{32}</checksum2>)")
    var match = regexp.exec(string)

    string = string.replace(match[1], "<checksum2>" + bytesToHex(rc4("bns_gamepic", hexToBytes(md5(pic)))) + "</checksum2>")

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        data[i] = string.charCodeAt(i)
    }
    return data
}

function process() {
    if(document.getElementById("custom").value == ""){
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="Chose Image!";
    }
    else{
        var valid = "convert.jpg";
        var custom = document.getElementById('custom').files[0]
        var readerValid = new FileReader()
        readerValid.onloadend = function(e) {
            var exif = piexif.load(e.target.result)
            var readerCustom = new FileReader()
            readerCustom.onloadend = function(e) {
                var image = new Image()
                image.onload = function() {
                    var result
                    try {
                        result = piexif.remove(e.target.result)
                    } catch (err) {
                        result = e.target.result
                    }
                    exif["Exif"][700] = UpdateChecksum(result, exif["Exif"][700])
                    result = piexif.insert(piexif.dump(exif), result)
                    download(result, "Converted_Image.jpg", "image/jpeg");
                }
                image.src = e.target.result
            }
            readerCustom.readAsDataURL(custom);
        };
        readerValid.readAsDataURL(valid);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me

Someone said:
The code var valid = "convert.jpg"; defines valid as a string, but the function readAsDataURL expect an object of type blob as a parameter, not a string.

But:

```
var valid = new Blob(["convert.jpg"], { type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

dont work :/

Comment: You are missing a lot semicolons at the end of you'r lines.

Comment: What is ``piexif``